# How to solve for conditional expectations with binary random variables?

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Suppose you have a binary random variable X with a probability of 50% 1, and a probability of 50% 0. Another random variable Y has the conditional expectation E[Y|X]=5. Another random variable W=XY-X.

Is the binary random variable X counted as .5 or 1/2 in the equation because that is the average value? So W=(.5)*5-(.5)?

Also, is E[W|X]=2?

Comment: W is a random variable, and therefore it's not equal to a number like (.5)*5-(.5).  You do an experiment, and get some outcome for X and Y, then you can compute W by doing W = XY - X

Comment: if E[Y|X] = const then E[Y] = same_const...., I would expect something like E[Y|X=x] = E[Y|X](x)= f(x) take a look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_random_variable

Answer (score 1):

It's not counted as 0.5 or any constant value in the equation because it is a random variable. We leave it as $X$. $E[Y|X]$ is in general random and is a function of $X$, but it can still evaluate to a constant, for example $Y$ is independent of $X$.

For calculating the expected value of $W$ given $X$, we have:
$$E[W|X]=E[XY-X|X]=XE[Y|X]-X=4X$$

And, still you can't put 0.5 or something in place of $X$. However, we can calculate statistics like:
$$E[W]=E[E[W|X]]=E[4X]=4E[X]=2$$
$$E[W|X=1]=4, E[W|X=0]=0$$